# Can't catch exception between services in Grails

Tags: exception, grails, grails-controller

I'm trying to catch an exception between two services but the catch code is unreachable. Does any one knows why?

**Controller:**

```
def controllerMethod() {
    try {
        service1.execute()
    } catch(CustomException ce) {
        // unreachable code
    }
}
```

**Service 1:**

```
def service2

def service1Method() {
    try {
        service2.execute()
    } catch(CustomException ce) {
        // unreachable code
        throw ce
    }
}
```

**Service 2:**

```
def service2Method() {
    throw new CustomException("exception")
}
```

**Exception:**

```
class CustomException extends Exception {
    CustomException(String message){
        super(message)
    }
}
```

Running Sample: https://bitbucket.org/victor-giacomo/grails-exception-propagation/src/master/

Comment: You have `throws ce` rather than `throw ce` in service 1 catch, guessing that's a typo when writing question. I've copied you example with grails 5 and don't have any issues, is your actual implementation more complex involving database transactions maybe?

Comment: Yes it was a typo. I fixed. The service1Method have a transaction and I'm using Grails 3.1

Answer (score 1):

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoaresexception](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoaresexception).

[grails-app/services/victorsoaresexception/Service1Service.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoaresexception/blob/e807b953d3b7f40c18744249214b91f3cf665a61/grails-app/services/victorsoaresexception/Service1Service.groovy)

```
package victorsoaresexception

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional
class Service1Service {
    Service2Service service2Service

    def service1Method() {
        try {
            service2Service.service2Method()
        } catch(CustomException ce) {
            // unreachable code
            throw ce
        }
    }
}
```

[grails-app/services/victorsoaresexception/Service2Service.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoaresexception/blob/main/grails-app/services/victorsoaresexception/Service2Service.groovy)

```
package victorsoaresexception

class Service2Service {

    def service2Method() {
        throw new CustomException("exception")
    }
}
```

[grails-app/controllers/victorsoaresexception/DemoController.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/victorsoaresexception/blob/main/grails-app/controllers/victorsoaresexception/DemoController.groovy)

```
package victorsoaresexception

class DemoController {

    Service1Service service1Service
    def controllerMethod() {
        try {
            service1Service.service1Method()
            render "No Exception  Was Thrown"
        } catch(CustomException ce) {
            render "CustomException was thrown, and caught by controller"
        }
    }
}
```

That all appears to work:

```
$ [main] http :8080/demo/controllerMethod
HTTP/1.1 200 
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 28 Dec 2022 18:03:39 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers

CustomException was thrown, and caught by controller


$
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to reproduce this in my grails version and then I'll tell you

Comment: "Thanks! " - You are welcome. "I'll try to reproduce this in my grails version and then I'll tell you" - Sounds good.  There are no versions of Grails for which this wouldn't work.  If you can share an example that doesn't make sense I would be happy to look at it and send you a PR.

Comment: @VictorSoares Have you been able to reproduce a problematic situation similar to the one described in the question?

Comment: I added the running sample with the situation. /test1 does not work and /test2 works

Comment: I think the commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/grails-exception-propagation/commit/402a9f1f12f113f749727580d6722348a522d001 changes the behavior you are referencing.

Comment: I don't know why but it solves the problem